# App once paid, now free, give benefits to people who paid?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app right now that I am planning to put onto Google play as a paid app. I know that one can decide at a later date to make the app free. I'm thinking that I might one day want to make the app free, selling some of the features that are now included in the paid version. Is there a way that I can tell if a user paid for an app?

Comment: Have you looked into the license api? Might be something there if you release them as separate apps. http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html

Comment: I guess the problem is right now that I haven't really decided how I want to make money from my app... I guess I could always release the paid version now, have a free version later that upgrades to the full version, but that is a bit of a hassle. Hmmm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I can suggest is to put some `SharedPreference` in your app marks it as "paid", then release a new version of your app which does not have this (when you make it free). Then, you can check the flag to see if it was there before it went free.

The downside to this is that root users *may be able* to change that value, if they were to discover it. Another downside is that clearing the data would clear the flag.

To avoid those downsides, you could store the data in a webserver database, but this seems like a fair bit of extra work for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a SharedPreference, as Eric suggests, but encode your value; instead of using true or yes, use a hash of the device ID so that no one can post that value for use on other devices.  Then you can just recompute the hash when testing this indicator, to ensure it is your own value and not one entered by a user.